# Centre Responsive Navigation Icons

Tags: html, css

Is anybody able to help?

Struggling to centre these icons and make them responsive to the width of the screen.

I am trying to get these icons to come closer as the screens width is changed
I've been trying to give the margins a '%' "as you can see by my code" so that they would shrink with the width and come closer to each other but it really is not coming out the way i was expecting it to! This seems simple but i cant cant get! cheers guys

```css
html, body {
  background-color:#B0B0B0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black; 
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
}
.navigationbar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #1BD2E1;
  color: white;

}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.logo-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  width: 90%;
}
.blockicon {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px; 
  top: 45px;
  background: #A81D1F;
  border-radius: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationbar">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="blockicon"></div>
    <div class="blockicon"></div>
    <div class="blockicon"></div>
    <div class="blockicon"></div>
    <div class="blockicon"></div>
    <div class="blockicon"></div>
  </div></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Here is an example.

If you want the boxes to "shrink" when there is not enough place, give them a margin. They will get smaller to preserve this margin when required.

```css
html, body {
  background-color:#B0B0B0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black; 
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
}
.navigationbar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #1BD2E1;
  color: white;

}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 300px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

}
.logo-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.blockicon {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px; 
  top: 45px;
  background:#A81D1F;
  border-radius: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationbar">
  <div class="logo-container" >
    <div class="blockicon">
    </div>
    <div class="blockicon">
    </div>
    <div class="blockicon">
    </div>
    <div class="blockicon">
    </div>
    <div class="blockicon">
    </div>
    <div class="blockicon">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

You may have to prefix it for old browsers. [Current support is ~95% with prefixes and ~80% without prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: This works but i cant have the icons shrink, i was after the width of the margin between each icon box to get smaller when the width of the screen shrinks, so it fits on smaller screens
Though i will research flex box's as i have never used them, they seem really useful :)

Comment: Add a margin to the "icons". Now they should shrink. Have a look at my edit. And yes, flexible boxes are awesome ;).

Comment: Thank you this looks good and can edit from this, appreciate your reply! :)